# Doesn’t WPA2 work together with my Network card?

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa2

How can I connect safely to WIFI without creating a security risk in Windows 11? My Network card/adapter/driver is:

> "Realtek RTL8822CE  802.11.AC  PCIE"

Do I have to use it together with safety type 802.11, or can I also use it together with WPA2, which is more secure…

When I tried it yesterday with WPA2 it worked fine for about 2 hours, and then the network stopped working…

So, could WPA2 be incompatible with my Network card?

Comment: The encryption type is defined by the AP (WiFi router, etc.), not your WiFi card. Your WiFi card has to support it otherwise it won't connect. As such your question is nonsensical.

Comment: WPA2 jhas been around for a long time. Update the card drivers and if you have router, upgrade the firmware in the router.

Comment: What leads you to believe that WPA2 is the reason for your wireless network dropping?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to use it together with safety type 802.11

There's no such safety type. 802.11 by itself is just the standard for "Wi-Fi in general".

> or can I also use it together with WPA2, which is more secure

All 802.11n and later devices (including your 802.11ac device) fully support WPA2. (I *think* it's a certification requirement by now.)

> could WPA2 be a little too “strong” for my Netwok card?

No. Either the card's firmware supports it, or doesn't.

If it does support WPA2, then the continuous operation of AES is "practically free" in the overall scale; it's usually done in dedicated circuitry and doesn't cause any significant load, overheating, or anything like that.

Comment: I´m glad to hear that I should use WPA2 and not my other option. 802.11.xx, and I will try to connect to WIFI automatically.  My Networkcard doesnn´t support WPA3, but that doesn´t matter…  :)

Comment: Are you confusing 802.11 with 802.1X?